# ASIHTTPRequest crash in ASIInputStream forwardInvocation:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, asihttprequest

Does somebody else has randomly seen crashes in ASIInputStream forwardInvocation: during the use of ASIFormDataRequest? (the request was startAsynchronous)

Here is the backtrace:

```
#0  0x95877b83 in CFRunLoopSourceSignal ()
#1  0x958daa45 in _CFStreamScheduleWithRunLoop ()
#2  0x9588d05d in __invoking___ ()
#3  0x9588cfc8 in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()
#4  0x958c8f28 in -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] ()
#5  0x0001d7ee in -[ASIInputStream forwardInvocation:] (self=0x228d40, _cmd=0x972d80c0, anInvocation=0x225a70) at /Users/catlan/Projekte/TBU/ASIInputStream.m:75
#6  0x9588de54 in ___forwarding___ ()
#7  0x9588d982 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#8  0x958da8f8 in CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop ()
#9  0x958daa26 in _CFStreamScheduleWithRunLoop ()
#10 0x958daa26 in _CFStreamScheduleWithRunLoop ()
#11 0x00015d4d in -[ASIHTTPRequest scheduleReadStream] (self=0x2318e0, _cmd=0x23490) at /Users/catlan/Projekte/TBU/ASIHTTPRequest.m:2608
#12 0x0000de97 in -[ASIHTTPRequest startRequest] (self=0x2318e0, _cmd=0x23827) at /Users/catlan/Projekte/TBU/ASIHTTPRequest.m:1005
#13 0x0000b56c in -[ASIHTTPRequest main] (self=0x2318e0, _cmd=0x973cfd56) at /Users/catlan/Projekte/TBU/ASIHTTPRequest.m:624
#14 0x0000b0a8 in -[ASIHTTPRequest startAsynchronous] (self=0x2318e0, _cmd=0x2136e) at /Users/catlan/Projekte/TBU/ASIHTTPRequest.m:546
#15 0x00004b0f in -[TBUploadWindowController requestUserInfo] (self=0x2f09e10, _cmd=0x205ed) at /Users/catlan/Projekte/TBU/TBUploadWindowController.m:119
#16 0x92591ad9 in __NSFireDelayedPerform ()
#17 0x95851edb in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#18 0x9584f864 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#19 0x9584f691 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#20 0x908fdf6c in RunCurrentEventLoopInMode ()
#21 0x908fdd23 in ReceiveNextEventCommon ()
#22 0x908fdba8 in BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode ()
#23 0x96b4eac5 in _DPSNextEvent ()
#24 0x96b4e306 in -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] ()
#25 0x96b1049f in -[NSApplication run] ()
#26 0x96b08535 in NSApplicationMain ()
#27 0x00002c8c in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff858) at /Users/catlan/Projekte/TBU/main.m:13
```

Any idea on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in ASIHTTPRequest I fixed earlier today, so grab a new copy and hopefully that will resolve the problem.

My apologies to everyone who got caught by this. Clearly, I need more tests! ;)

Comment: Thx Ben, this did fix the issue. Also check your mail I send you some changes along.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that rel. 1.6 fixes this problem. I had it also (strangely, it was working perfectly in the simulator but crashing on the device) and this new version fixes it.
Thanks to the developers for the fix (other than the whole package!) and to catlan for reporting the problem.